# Refreshing a table in SQL server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have opened a table in SQL server management studio express.

How do I update it? 
As changes made outside the studio application do not show unless I close and reopen the table. Surely there must be a better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean with *opening* the table? Editing top 200 rows? Selecting top 1000 rows?

Comment: I have been right click -> open table

Comment: Must be something from the Express version. My management studio version doesn't have an open table option.

Comment: That's what it was in 2005. Open Table is not the way you should be viewing data in Management Studio... use a normal query window. Want to refresh? Run your query again. It's not a live web app that updates for you in real time, the query you ran is only valid at the time you ran it.

Comment: You can hit Ctrl+R to re-execute the query which will refresh the data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand exactly what you want, but if you want to see the changes, the query that loaded the table has to be re-executed. You can do this by clicking on "Execute SQL" (or selecting it from the context menu).

Depending on what you mean with "opening the table" (select top x rows, edit top x rows, etc ) you also might try to hit <kbd>F5</kbd> (works for "Select TOP x Rows") - which simply executes the previous statement.

Comment: I see. so I have to execute a statement (select * from x). I have been right click -> open table.

Answer (score 21):

In **SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

In **Visual Studio** Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, manually editing data in SQL Server is a **bad practice**.

- It's not repeatable.  Anything you do is limited to your window and once it's gone it's gone.
- It's easy to make mistakes.  Click the wrong cell, fat-finger a decimal point, etc.

A much better solution is to create and save insert or update scripts.  These are editable, reviewable, and rerunnable.

If you need to recreate your database or replicate something now, you need to manually type in all the same values you typed in before.  If you script it out, you just run the script and can have the same data as many times as you can hit `F5`.

Comment: While true, the OP wasn't talking about *updating* the data - just refreshing their current view of the data because changes were being made elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

It is much easier if you just create a query referencing on that table. Then create select statement giving all rows from that table.